# On ruled surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $E,F,G,L,M,N$ are the the coefficients of the first and second fundamental forms of a  surface. How can I say that the surface is a ruled surface or not? (Only with using these coefficients)

Answer (score 3):

Let denote the coefficients of second fundamental form by $e, g $ and $f$. Now given a one parameter family of lines $\brace\alpha(t),w(t) $, the parametrized surface$$X(t,v)=\alpha(t)+vw(t)$$ is called the ruled surface generated by above family.

Now the coefficient $g$ is for this surface given by$$g={\langle}\frac{X_t\wedge X_v}{|X_t\wedge X_v|},X_{vv}\rangle  $$
Now  $X_{vv}=0$
$\implies g=0$

So coefficient $g$ of second fundamental form is always 0 for a ruled surface.